# ANTLR parser to throw exception for "true and or false" statement

Tags: antlr4

I'm using ANTLR 4 and have a fairly complex grammar. I'm trying to simplify here...

Given an expression like: `true and or false` I want a parsing error since the operands defined expect expressions on either side and this has an expr operand operand expr

My reduced grammar is:

```
grammar MappingExpression;

/* The start rule; begin parsing here.
   operator precedence is implied by the ordering in this list */


// =======================
// = PARSER RULES
// =======================

expr:
 | op=(TRUE|FALSE)                               # boolean
 | expr op=AND expr                              # logand
 | expr op=OR expr                               # logor
 ;

TRUE : 'true';
FALSE : 'false';
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;              // ignore whitespace
AND : 'and';
OR : 'or';
```

however, it seems that the parser stops after evaluating true even though it has all four tokens identified (e.g., alt state returned becomes 2 in the parser).

If I can't get a parsing exception (because it is seeing what I deem operands as expressions), if I got the entire parse tree I could throw a runtime exception for two operands in a row (e.g., 'and' and 'or').

Originally, I'd just had:

```
expr 'and' expr #logand
expr 'or' expr #logor
```

and this suffered the same parsing problem (stopping early).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get a parsing error if you force the parser to consume all tokens by "anchoring" a rule with the built-in `EOF`

```
parse
 : expr EOF
 ;
```

This is what I get when parsing the input `true and or false`:

[image]

See the error in the lower left corner:

```
line 1:9 extraneous input 'or' expecting {'true', 'false'}
line 1:17 missing {'true', 'false'} at '<EOF>'
```

Comment: I added this but still behaves the same. input.tokens for "true and or false" are only for the first 3:

    `[[@0,0:3='true',<10>,1:0], [@1,5:7='and',<39>,1:5], [@2,9:10='or',<40>,1:9]]`

and it fails the test in my MappingExpressionParser below because alt is set to 2 on the line before the while test after it has parsed true from the input:  

    `_alt = getInterpreter().adaptivePredict(_input,14,_ctx);`  

    `while ( _alt!=2 && _alt!=org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN.INVALID_ALT_NUMBER ) {`

Comment: I don't know how you're testing things, but see my edited answer with the errors I get. Could you update your question with an SSCCE that demonstrates `true and or false` not producing an error?

Comment: I believe your answer is correct and will check it. In my case, this has required some code changes to no longer call expr but expr_to_eof (what I called your parse...) and then I have to override the visitChildren method to avoid reaching the TerminalNode containing the EOF Token so I don't lose the result that was accumulating before reaching the EOF. You are correct, using this approach does report a syntax error for the or. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It turns out parsing to EOF has introduced some other issues I'm having to address.

Comment: I'll return and provide more details for the Java implications of adding the EOF processing when I've addressed the side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Bart Kiers answer above is correct. I just wanted to provide more details for people working with Java who have experienced incomplete parsing issues.

I'd had a fairly complex g4 file that defined an expr as a series of OR'ed rules associated with tags (e.g., following a # that become the method name in the ExpressionsVisitor). While this seemed to work there were situations where I'd expected parsing errors but received none. I also had situations where only part of an input to the parser was interpreted making it impossible to process the entire input statement.

I repaired the g4 file as follows (the full version is [here](https://github.com/IBM/JSONata4Java/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/com/api/jsonata4java/expressions/generated/MappingExpression.g4)):

```
// =======================
// = PARSER RULES
// =======================

expr_to_eof : expr EOF ;

expr:
   ID                                                     # id
 | '*'                                                    # field_values
 | DESCEND                                                # descendant
 | DOLLAR                                                 # context_ref
 | ROOT                                                   # root_path
 | ARR_OPEN exprOrSeqList? ARR_CLOSE                      # array_constructor
 | OBJ_OPEN fieldList? OBJ_CLOSE                          # object_constructor
 | expr '.' expr                                          # path
 | expr ARR_OPEN ARR_CLOSE                                # to_array
 | expr ARR_OPEN expr ARR_CLOSE                           # array
 | expr OBJ_OPEN fieldList? OBJ_CLOSE                     # object
 | VAR_ID (emptyValues | exprValues)                      # function_call
 | FUNCTIONID varList '{' exprList? '}'                   # function_decl
 | VAR_ID ASSIGN (expr | (FUNCTIONID varList '{' exprList? '}'))                   # var_assign
 | (FUNCTIONID varList '{' exprList? '}') exprValues                               # function_exec
 | op=(TRUE|FALSE)                                        # boolean
 | op='-' expr                                            # unary_op
 | expr op=('*'|'/'|'%') expr                             # muldiv_op
 | expr op=('+'|'-') expr                                 # addsub_op
 | expr op='&' expr                                       # concat_op
 | expr op=('<'|'<='|'>'|'>='|'!='|'=') expr              # comp_op
 | expr 'in' expr                                         # membership
 | expr 'and' expr                                        #logand
 | expr 'or' expr                                         # logor
 | expr '?' expr (':' expr)?                              # conditional
 | expr CHAIN expr                                        # fct_chain
 | '(' (expr (';' (expr)?)*)? ')'                         # parens
 | VAR_ID                                                 # var_recall
 | NUMBER                                                 # number
 | STRING                                                 # string
 | 'null'                                                 # null
 ;
```

Based on Bart's suggestion I added the top rule for expr_to_eof that resulted in that method being added to the MappingExpressionParser. So, in my Expressions class where before I'd called `tree = parser.expr();` I now needed to call `tree = parser.expr_to_eof();` which resulted in a ParseTree that included a last child for the Token.EOF.

Because my code needed to check some conditions for the first and last step performed it was easiest for me to add the following to strip out the `<EOF>` and get back the ParseTree (ExprContext rather than Expr_to_eofContext) I had been using by adding this statement:

```
newTree = ((Expr_to_eofContext)tree).expr();
```

So, overall, it was quite easy to fix a long standing bug (and others I'd postponed addressing) just by adding the new rule in the .g4 file and changing the parser so it would parse to end of file () and then extract the entire expression that was parsed.

I expect this will allow me to add considerably more functions to JSONata4Java to match the JavaScript version jsonata.js

Thanks again Bart!